# How to check events for previous days

Tags: google-fabric

I am looking for a way to get the events for previous days/months. Currently, I can see the events on the Answers dashboard for last 5 days only.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Right now we display data for 90 days historically in our event dashboards. If you are seeing less than this please reach out to our support team.

[image: 90 day graph]

Comment: Dear Todd, Thanks for your response. I created a custom event and when i look into the events dashboard i can see only events for last 5 days only. Please find attached snapshot here:https://imgur.com/FMH8F0f